# Different output in different exe files Python

Tags: python, window, exe

I have been working on an automation script which includes shutting down my Windows 10 pro machine.

Here is one Python code which turned to exe file

```
import os
import time as t
import re
while True:
```

To check for "sd" in a file

```
    lst = os.listdir("attachments")[-1]
        with open(f"attachments\\{lst}", "r") as f:
            message = f.read()
    x = re.search("sd", message)
```

if "sd" is found then the file must be deleted and the computer must be shut down

```
    if x:
        print("YESSSS")
        os.remove(f"attachments\\{lst}")
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
    t.sleep(5)
```

The problem is that after deleting the file instead of shutting down the PC the cmd.exe appears on my screen...idk its weird
[click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGHT3.png)

to check if the exe format didnt have any problems i created another exe file
here is the code

```
import os
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

Turns out there is nothing wrong with the exe format...it performs normal shutdown....god just doesn't like me

Please help me